# Oddly satisfying $\mathbb{P}^\infty$

Tags: vector-spaces, prime-numbers

Some time ago I came up with an idea of an infinitely-dimensional space that I personally call $\mathbb{P}^\infty$ or a *prime powers* space. It is probably known already, but I haven't found any references to it. I'd like to know is there any use for this besides just being a brain teaser.

Definition and properties:

- Every positive rational number can be uniquely represented by a point in $\mathbb{P}^\infty$. Coordinates of such point correspond to prime factorization of the number. For example, 42 has the coordinates $(1,1,0,1)$ since $42 = 2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^0 \cdot 7^1$, and $2/9$ is $(1,-2)$.
- By definition, all prime numbers form a unit sphere of radius 1.
- The space origin corresponds to number 1 since $p^0 = 1$ for every prime number $p$.
- Amusingly, 0 does not map to any point in $\mathbb{P}^\infty$
- Negative numbers, somewhat awkwardly, can be introduced using $i^2 = -1$

Questions:

- Was this object known before?
- Is there a way to analytically extend it beyond rationals?
- What lies between the grid lines, say, between $2^1$ and $2^2$?
- What is the meaning of translation or rotation of a figure in such space?
- What would be the metric?
- It is known that some geometric facts are formulated more easily in a proper coordinate system. For example, many functions are trivially defined using polar coordinates. Are there any mathematical facts that could be conveniently formulated using this space?

Comment: Check out this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879/mapping-natural-numbers-into-prime-exponents-space)

Comment: By the way, $\mathbb{P}^{\infty}$ as notation is sometimes used to refer to infinite projective space (the infinite version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is essentially a special case of the construction of [fractional ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal) of a Dedekind domain, in this case $\mathbb{Z}$. Fractional ideals can be defined for [rings of integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers) of number fields $K$ which generalize $\mathbb{Z}$, such as the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. More geometric (in the sense of algebraic geometry) examples are also possible; see [divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_(algebraic_geometry)).

Abstractly the group of fractional ideals of a Dedekind domain $D$ is always [free abelian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group) on the [prime ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal) of $D$ (this is a version of unique factorization for ideals, which is one of the defining features of Dedekind domains), so each fractional ideal can be specified by a list of coordinates giving the exponent of each prime ideal. This use of "prime coordinates" is a neat way to see very concretely the effects of operations such as gcd and lcm, but I'm not aware of any extremely common name for it.